# Error: elixir_make 0.6.1 RETIRED! (invalid) Wrong permissions on the mix.exs file

Tags: elixir

When I run:

```
mix deps.get
```

I get:

```
  elixir_make 0.6.1 RETIRED!
    (invalid) Wrong permissions on the mix.exs file
```

as part of the output.

I don't see `elixir-make` as one of the dependencies in the `mix.exs` file, nor is it in `mix.lock`

The permissions on the file:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff   2584 Feb 24 10:51 mix.exs
```

Can't find anything about this on the internet.

Anybody have any idea what's going on or what the right permissions should be?

```
# mix.exs

      {:argon2_elixir, "~> 2.3"},
      {:ecto_sql, "~> 3.4"},
      {:envy, "~> 1.1.1"},
      {:ex_machina, "~> 2.4", only: :test},
      {:exvcr, "~> 0.11", only: :test},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
      {:guardian, "~> 2.1"},
      {:httpoison, "~> 1.8"},
      {:jason, "~> 1.0"},
      {:mock, "~> 0.3.0", only: :test},
      {:phoenix, "~> 1.5.6"},
      {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 4.1"},
      {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.11"},
      {:phoenix_live_dashboard, "~> 0.3 or ~> 0.2.9"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.2", only: :dev},
      {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.0"},
      {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
      {:quantum, "~> 3.0"},
      {:telemetry_metrics, "~> 0.4"},
      {:telemetry_poller, "~> 0.4"},
      {:ueberauth, "~> 0.6.3"},
      {:ueberauth_identity, "~> 0.3.0"},
      {:wallaby, "~> 0.28.0", [runtime: false, only: :test]}
```

```
$ elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 23 [erts-11.1.8] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]

Elixir 1.11.3 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 23)
```

Comment: What version of elixir and erlang are you running?

Comment: Show the `deps` section of your `mix.exs`, please. One of the dependencies you use requires `elixir_make` of a wrong version. Probable adding an explicit `{:elixir_make, "~>0.6.2", override: true}` would fix the issue.